# Dynamically add key value pair to options property of woocommerce checkout fields filter

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am adding some custom fields to woocommerce checkout using `woocommerce_checkout_fields` filter. One of those fields is a `select` dropdown. This is my code for the fields.

```
// Add a new checkout field
function ds_filter_checkout_fields($fields){
    $suburb = ds_get_delivery_suburbs();
    $postcodes = ds_get_delivery_postcodes();
    $fields['extra_fields'] = array(
        'some_field' => array(
            'type' => 'text',
            'required'      => true,
            'label' => __( 'Some field' )
        ),
        'select_field' => array(
            'type' => 'select',
            'options' => array('key' => 'value'),
            'required'      => true,
            'label' => __( 'Another field' )
        )
    );

    return $fields;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'ds_filter_checkout_fields' );
```

If you check the `select_field` code there is a `options` property and it takes key and value pair ... I want to insert dynamic key and dynamic value to `options` property ... In the code I am getting the dynamic `key` from `$postcodes` and dynamic `value` from `$suburb` and when I try to insert it like this `'options' => array($postcodes => $suburb),` I get this warning `Warning: Illegal offset type` ... I have tried couple of other methods but they didn't work so I turned to you guys ... I appreciate your help ... looking forward to your responses.

**NOTE: I have googled this but haven't found any answers so that is why I turned to Stackoverflow for help.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want it to be dynamic you have to first set and fill the array and then use it, so it would be

```
// Add a new checkout field
function ds_filter_checkout_fields($fields){
    $suburb = ds_get_delivery_suburbs();
    $postcodes = ds_get_delivery_postcodes();
    $ma_options[$postcodes] = $suburb; 
    $fields['extra_fields'] = array(
        'some_field' => array(
            'type' => 'text',
            'required'      => true,
            'label' => __( 'Some field' )
        ),
        'select_field' => array(
            'type' => 'select',
            'options' => $ma_options[$postcodes],
            'required'      => true,
            'label' => __( 'Another field' )
        )
    );

    return $fields;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'ds_filter_checkout_fields' );
```

If it doesn't work then share var_dump($ma_options);

--- UPDATE

That could happen because of index not existing or passing something which isn't an string as the key. You should cast your type to string if desired efect, or use stdClass object.